# cURL ignores options

Tags: php, curl

The following cURL configuration works fine on my local machine using cURL 7.30.0:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    // Just showing the noteworthy options here.
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER   => array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0,
    CURLOPT_COOKIE       => "foo=bar",
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Excerpt of the debugging output:

```
> GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: example.com
Accept: */*
Cookie: foo=bar
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Now I run the same code on a shared hosting environment with cURL 7.19.7 and get:

```
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Basically cURL is working 99% fine, but ignores the forced HTTP version and cookie string. Is the hosting company running a configuration that blocks these features? Is the cURL version they are running too old? What's going on here?

Comment: Check the version of CURL running at both. Also, if you're making HTTP requests from PHP I'd recommend against cURL and in favor of a better more modern HTTP client like https://github.com/rdlowrey/Artax

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. I've added version numbers to the question. Thanks for the tip too, bookmarked it. I'm improving existing cURL code right now though, so it'd be easier to solve this issue for my current project than rewrite the whole thing.

Comment: Have you asked the support dept at the hosting company? They may shed some light on your issue. I must say that i appreciate why you are puzzled by the different results returned by 'cUrl' in what appear to be similar circumstances.

Comment: I'm waiting on a reply from the hosting company Ryan, but SO is usually a gazillion times quicker and more detailed :).

Comment: I really cannot see how this could be due to libcurl versions or anything. The cookie and the HTTP version functionality have been working solidly and the same for MANY years... (I wrote that code and maintain libcurl)

Comment: Hi Daniel, honored to have you here. I guess I should conclude the hosting company is changing stuff on a configuration level then.

Comment: I found the culprit - should've done a sanity check on `curl_setopt_array` as it stops processing if a single option fails. Thanks for chiming in you three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it. `curl_setopt_array` quits processing options as soon as one option fails, I didn't know that. I should've checked the return value to make sure all was well.

In my case the culprit was option `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`. It probably failed because the hosting provider is using safe mode, which disables the follow 301/302 feature.

```
$curl = curl_init();

$check = curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);

if(!$check)
    die("Ye be warned: one of your options did not make it.");

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```